# Does mcrypt_generic vulnerable to padding oracle attack?

Tags: php, security

Padding oracle attack needs to padding bytes like 0x01, 0x02... so we could know which byte we sent is correct. For example:

```
b1 xor middle_str = 0x01
so: 
middle_str = 0x01 xor b1
b2 xor middle_str = anybytewewant
b2 = 0x01 xor b1 xor anybytewewant
```

But mcrypt_generic() use 0x00 to padding, and it seems just use rtrim 0x00 to unpadding before decrypt.

```php
echo bin2hex(mdecrypt_generic($this->demcrypt, hex2bin('5061726101676f6e0003000000')));
echo bin2hex(mdecrypt_generic($this->demcrypt, hex2bin('5061726101676f6e0003')));
//66a8dc339ae2377f857a398e1086b1e5
//66a8dc339ae2377f857a398e1086b1e5
```

I cannot determine which byte at last could cause Error because it just rtrim 0x00 without any other check.

Answer (score 0):

Trimming the 0x00 bytes is not what the padding oracle attack is about. The padding oracle attack is about being able to differentiate during decryption if the encryption failed due to wrong padding or not. You just play with XORing the last bytes of the ciphertext with different values and look at the outcome. Will the decryption fail and if it will then with what message/exception?

Out of what you has shown there is no way of telling if the method is vulnerable or not.

If you want to learn more about crypto in general, and the padding oracle in particular, then there is this crypto online course by prof. Boneh that rocks: https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I am confused about is, assuming that we can differentiate during decryption if the encryption failed due to wrong padding or not, we still cannot perform padding oracle attack because of the trimming of 0x00.